# Getting the sum of all even numbers in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to get the sum of all even numbers with a function in Haskell, but it doesn't seem to work.

This is how my code looks like:

```
sumEvenNumbers :: [Int] -> Int
sumEvenNumbers n = sum . even
```

Anyone has a solution to this? Thanks!

Comment: Hint: what's the type of `sum . even`? What does `sumEvenNumbers n` indicate? Furthermore, does `sum . even` make sense, taking into account the type signatures of `sum` and `even`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `sumEvenNumbers = sum . filter even` (note the absence of the argument on the left-hand side of the equation). `even` doesn’t work on lists, but on single integers.

A more explicit equivalent is `sumEvenNumbers xs = sum (filter even xs)`.

Answer (score 4):

The type of `even` is `even :: (Integral a) => a -> Bool`, meaning you give it a number and it tells you whether it is even or not. You are trying to apply this function to a list of numbers which doesn't make sense.

What you want instead is a function that gives you back a list of the numbers that are even. To accomplish that you want `filter` which has the type `filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`, and it will apply the function to the original list and give back only those things that evaluated to True.

Additionally, when you are going to define a function point-free style, you don't need to (actually, language does not allow you to) give arguments to the function, so the `n` is unnecessary.